# How to convert a simple array into json format?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've an array titled $error_msg as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  Please select the class 
    [1] =>  Please select the test package 
    [2] =>  Please select the section 
    [3] =>  Please select the test 
)
```

Now I want to convert it into json format as follows:

```
{"error_message":"Please select the class<br>Please select the test package<br>Please select the section<br>Please select the test<br>"}
```

How can I achieve this? Can anyone help me in this regard please?

Comment: Tried `echo json_encode($error_msg);` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$string = implode("<br />", $array);
$json = json_encode( array('error_message'=>$string) );
```

Comment: should be `implode("<br>", $array)`

Comment: depends on the used HTML Doctype ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
/*Array
(
[0] =>  Please select the class 
[1] =>  Please select the test package 
[2] =>  Please select the section 
[3] =>  Please select the test 
)*/ your array as $data
for($v=0;$v<count($data);$v++)
{
    $retrieval[$v]['id'] = $data[$v];
}
echo json_encode($retrieval);
```

Comment: This isn't what he asked for, `retrieval` output: `[{"id":"Please select the class "},{"id":"Please select the test package"},{"id":"Please select the section"},{"id":"Please select the test"}]`. @jogesh_pi response should be accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
<?php

$input = array("Please select the class", "Please select the test package", "Please select the section ","Please select the test ");
$message = "";
foreach ($input as $line) {
    $message .= $line."<br/>";
}
$error = array('error_message' => $message);
echo json_encode($error, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); // Make sure slashes aren't escaped
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$error_msg  =   array
                    (' Please select the class ',
                       'Please select the test package ',
                       ' Please select the section ',
                       'Please select the test ',
                    );

echo json_encode(array('error_msg'=>join("&ltbr&gt",$error_msg)));
```